# How does this C multiply function correspond to assembly, and what integer type is it using?

Tags: assembly, x86, att

Okay, so I have a function:

```
void store_prod(num_t *dest, unsigned x, num_t y){
 *dest = x*y;
}
```

now, according to the book, GCC generates the following assembly code
(dest at `%ebp+8`, x at `%ebp+12`, y at `%ebp+16`)

```
1. movl 12(%ebp), %eax
2. movl 20(%ebp),%ecx 
3. imull %eax,%ecx 
4. mull 16(%ebp) 
5. leal (%ecx, %edx), %edx
6. movl 8(%ebp),%ecx 
7. movl %eax, (%ecx) 
8. movl %edx, 4(%ecx)
```

I need to find out what kind of data type is `num_t` and to describe the algorithm used to compute the product and argue that it is correct.

Mind you, this isn't homework, just a practice problem in a book. However, I'd be glad to have some insight, as unsigned vs signed division is getting hazy.

Comment: This isn't 64-bit code, otherwise it would just use `imulq %rdi, %rsi` after zero-extending `x` to 64-bit.  Why do you say "64-bit execution" in the title?  `num_t` is `uint64_t`, but this is 32-bit code.  One-operand `mul` is an unsigned multiply (the difference matters only for the high-half.)  http://felixcloutier.com/x86/MUL.html

Comment: Well, I looked in the back of the chapter, it said the answer to " what is the data type of num_t" was that it was 64 bit and that it was using 64 bit long long types. I suppose I was a little confused on what the book was trying to tell me, its like a flood of info that expects you to know every droplet and doesn't stop to remind you that they existed, this book is a beast.

Comment: Yeah, the code runs in 32-bit mode, but operates on 64-bit integer types.  That's why it has to use two multiply instructions to implement 32 x 64-bit unsigned multiplication, adding the high halves using LEA.  (So `num_t` isn't `long long`, it's `unsigned long long`, which `uint64_t` is a typedef for on 32-bit systems.)  You can just try it on https://godbolt.org/z/HspdJO and see it's correct.  And that you'd get `imul` with signed `long long`.

Comment: It makes sense, thanks Peter.